# Search results to show in blade using ajax and laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a search place for costumers to search the product which will be displayed in blade. I am using ajax and laravel. Here is my code as much as I wrote. The query works well and when I print $filter I can see the results.

```
$('.gotosearch').on('click' , function() {
    var search = $(this).val()
    var inpvalue = $('.form-control').val()

    $.ajax({
        url:'/searchproducts',
        type:'post',
        data: {
            inpvalue,
            "_token" : token
        },
        success:function(r) {
            console.log(r)  
        }
    })
})
```

```html
Route::post('/searchproducts' , 'ProductController@searchproducts');

function searchproducts(Request $search) {
    $filter = ProductModel::where('Product_Name','LIKE', $search->inpvalue.'%')->get();
}
```

Comment: Post the code where you are rendering the products

Answer (score 0):

You can use `response()->json` in you controller

As per Laravel documentation

> The json method will automatically set the Content-Type header to
>   application/json, as well as convert the given array to JSON using the
>   json_encode PHP function:

```
return response()->json([
    'name' => 'Abigail',
    'state' => 'CA'
]);
```

Try this:

`return response()->json($filters->toArray());`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#json-responses

Comment: Like this?        $filter = ProductModel::where('Product_Name','LIKE', $search->inpvalue.'%')->get();
        return response()->json([
            'Product_Name' => $filter
        ]);

Comment: Thank you. How can I display that ? Will it work in ajax?

Comment: ho to display in blade

Answer (score 0):

try this:
// search text

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" id="search" name="search" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Search" value="{{ old('accountNo') }}" style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;" required>
</div
```

// search result

```
<div id="getResult" class="panel panel-default" style="width:400px; height: 150px; overflow-y:auto; position:absolute; left:50px; top:180px; z-index:1; display:none;background-color:white">
   <div id="getList"></div>
</div>
```

//ajax

```
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $('#search').keyup(function(){
            var search = $('#search').val();
            if(search==""){
                $('#getResult').css('display', 'none').hide();
            }
            else{
                var getQueries = "";
                $.get("{{ url('/') }}" + '/search/' + search,
                    {search:search}, 
                    function(data){
                    if(data){
                        $('#getResult').css('display', 'block');
                    }else{
                        $('#getResult').css('display', 'none')
                    }
                    if(search == ''){
                        $('#getResult').css('display', 'none').hide();
                    }else{
                       $.each(data, function (index, value){
                            var id=value.ID;
                        getQueries += '<ul style="margin-top:3px; list-style-type:none;">';
                        getQueries += '<a href={{ url("add-contribution-amount")}}' +'/'+ value.id + '>' + value.fullname +' | '+value.accountno + '</a>';
                        getQueries += '</ul>';
                        });
                            $('#getList').html(getQueries );
                    }

                })
            }
        });

</script>
```

//controller

```
public function CustomerSearch($getSearch){

        $search = $getSearch;
        $members = DB::table('tblcustomers')
        ->where('accountno', 'like', "%$search%")
        ->select('id','branchID', 'fullname', 'savingstype', 'accountno')
        ->orderby('id','asc')
        ->get();

        return $members;

    }
```

//route

```
Route::get('/search/{searchQuerys?}',                'ContributionController@CustomerSearch');
```